# Edit git's commit comment

Tags: git, githooks

I have a little `prepare-commit-msg` hook script that does some basic timekeeping for me. It does some sums based on a few metrics and tells me how much time went into the current commit. This is for internal use and should not end up in the commit message.

What it currently does is inject a line like this.

```
# Time since last timed commit: ...
```

My problem with `prepare-commit-msg` is this line ends up in the actual commit message. I have to manually delete it each time or it'll be client-visible.

Ideally it would featured in the block that reads:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
```

But how do I print data in there?

Comment: Why do you use a `prepare-commit-msg` for this? Hooks are usually not very convenient because they are not replicated during the `clone`. So you could instead have a local git command (or alias) similar to `git describe`. When you hit `git timed` you get what you need. Moreover, I rarely open my editor when I commit. I usually do `git commit -am 'my commit message here...'`

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If it's not in the actual commit message, how do you use it? I thought "internal use" was that you could read it during editing the commit message. But it seems not so, because if it's seen in the actual commit message, you must have skipped the editing. You could consider using `git notes` in a `post-commit` hook, so that you can see notes in `git log` and later push commits without notes.

Comment: Normally lines lines starting with `#` shouldn't be included in the message. My guess would be that there is some other character before the `#`. For example, a line starting with ` #` is not a comment. Otherwise, maybe there could be an issue if there is an inconsistency in line break types. Is the line you are inserting using CRLF or only LF? Is that consistent with the "normal" default commit message? You could try doing `hexdump -C .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` after making a commit and try to inspect if there is some weird character that shouldn't be there.

Comment: The message gives me a *raw* number of hours since my last commit. **I** read that while I write the proper commit message and leave a little note, which another script picks up on when I generate my invoices. So again, I need this alongside the rest of the commit data, in the same place (eg my editor) but only for my consumption.

Comment: @Alderath Good idea. I insert two \n (aka, 0a, LF) chars before the #. Editors interpret that okay and all my other line endings are 0a.